# Find Out What Days an Event is On With Google Calendar?

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api

Is there any way for the Google Calendar to simply provide me with the name of the day of the week on which an event occurs? For instance, if I retrieve a list of events within a range of dates, like this:

```
events = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin='2012-12-24T00:00:00Z',
 timeMax='2012-12-30T23:59:59Z').execute()
```

Is there any way to look up a particular event within that list and find out what day it's on? Right now I'm using an awkward hack involving the 'date' and 'dateTime' in the Google Calendar API combined with Python's calendar module:

```
for calendar_list_entry in events['items']:
    try:
        year, month, day = calendar_list_entry['start']['date'].split('-')
        dayNum = calendar.weekday(int(year), int(month), int(day))
        print dayNum
        dayName = createDayName(dayNum)
        dayDict[dayName].append(calendar_list_entry['summary'])
        print dayDict[dayName]
    except:
        print calendar_list_entry['start']['dateTime'][:10].split('-')
        year, month, day = calendar_list_entry['start']['dateTime'][:10].split('-')
        dayNum = calendar.weekday(int(year), int(month), int(day))
        print dayNum
        dayName = createDayName(dayNum)
        dayDict[dayName].append(calendar_list_entry['summary'])
        print dayDict[dayName]
```

the createDayName function is simple:

```
def createDayName(dayNum):
    '''
    Takes as input a number generated from calendar.weekday and outputs the weekday name
    that is associated with that number.
    '''
    dayNameList = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
    return dayNameList[dayNum]
```

Surely there is a less cumbersome way to do this? I also run into serious problems for events spanning multiple days, i.e., Thursday-Saturday. I realize I could do some ridiculous math to split the days up, but there must be a better way for such a simple operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no direct way to get the day of an event in the Calendar API. If the date format of your results is as it is in your parameters (`2012-12-24T00:00:00Z`), you can use string formatting in combination with the `datetime` module. Here, the `%A` is the string formatting parameter that returns the day of the week of the datetime object defined by running `strptime` on our string with the corresponding format:

```
In [1]: from datetime import datetime

In [2]: s = '2012-12-24T00:00:00Z'

In [3]: d = datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')

In [4]: '{0:%A}'.format(d)
Out[4]: 'Monday'
```

And as a function:

```
In [8]: def createDayName(s):
   ...:     d = datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
   ...:     return '{0:%A}'.format(d)
   ...: 

In [9]: createDayName('2012-12-24T00:00:00Z')
Out[9]: 'Monday'

In [10]: createDayName('2012-12-30T23:59:59Z')
Out[10]: 'Sunday'
```

Building on that, if you need to handle multi-day events, you can try something like this, where the main piece involves `timedelta` and iterating the number of days between the two events (note that this is a bit arbitrary, but will hopefully provide a useful example):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# This structure will allow us to append to our dictionary without
# there needing to be a key first (comes in handy)
from collections import defaultdict


def days_in_range(start, end, daysDict):
    # Convert your start/end dates
    start_d = datetime.strptime(start, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
    end_d = datetime.strptime(end, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')

    # Now iterate over the days between those two dates, adding
    # an arbitrary value to the 'day' key of our dict
    for i in range((end_d - start_d).days + 1):
        day_name = '{0:%A}'.format(start_d + timedelta(days=i))
        daysDict[day_name].append(i)
    return daysDict


# Create your dictionary that will have a list as the default value
daysDict = defaultdict(list)

start = '2012-12-24T00:00:00Z'
end = '2012-12-30T23:59:59Z'

# I would probably reevaluate this part, but the reason for
# passing the dictionary itself to the function is so that
# it can better fit into situations where you have multiple events
# (although a class structure may be well-suited for this, but
# that may be overcomplicating things a bit :) )
daysDict = days_in_range(start, end, daysDict)

for day, value in daysDict.iteritems():
  print day, value
```

This prints the following (as dictionaries are inherently unordered, it may appear different for you):

```
Monday [0]
Tuesday [1]
Friday [4]
Wednesday [2]
Thursday [3]
Sunday [6]
Saturday [5]
```

Comment: That definitely cleans up my code a bit, but I'm still left with the problem of events spanning multiple days. I want each day in my dayDict to reflect that there is an event there. For this it seems like I'd have to iterate through event lists one day at a time instead of through a weeklong period. Is there another approach to this?

Comment: @user1427661 If you have a dictionary of days, and the end goal is to have each day entry contain a list of the events that took place on that day, then in order to handle multi-day events you will have to get the range of days in the interval and then append the event to each one individually. Are you only doing calls in week-long intervals? In other words, you won't run into the case where an event spans two Mondays? Or where you have two events that are on different Mondays?

Comment: Yeah, it's only in weeklong intervals. In theory, there could be events that span multiple weeks or recur at some later day, but it is for a weekly scheduling algorithm, so I only need to do this in weekly chunks. It seems like in order to find out what day a multi-day event fell upon, I'd need to iterate over each individual day, then increment the day using some calendar math probably involving epoch time.... unless there is another handy API/module solution.

Comment: @user1427661 I added something that will hopefully be of use - general idea is that you can use `timedelta` to set up a loop, and then use our code from before to determine which days to add to the dictionary. Happy to explain whatever doesn't make sense (or adjust if what I added is nonsense :) ).